# Once WDS Bridging, How make work ethernet ports for TPLink WR1043ND V1

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet

After spending hours on this,

I succeed to make a bridge from my original Wifi Repeater to the WR1043ND V1
I followed this : https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/440/

But if I try to reach a device, let's say 192.168.1.100 which is connected via Ethernet Port of the WR1043ND, I won't reach it if my Wifi is set to the first router.

Of course I can reach the WR1043ND using the IP set in `Network > Lan` but I can't understand why I could not reach other devices connected to this Wifi Repeater

```
Firmware Version:   
3.13.15 Build 140319 Rel.41339n
Hardware Version:   
WR1043ND v1 00000000
```

If spent many hours on various forum, but most of the solutions are related to a V2 or V3.

[image]

Comment: In the router's settings page, section “Wireless→Wireless Advanced”, is "Enabled AP Isolation" unchecked? If not, uncheck it and click Save.

Comment: It's already unchecked....

Comment: To be sure - the problem is when connecting to the WR1043ND or the repeater? Have you tested both?

Comment: WR1043ND is the repeater. Let's say I have my regular Wifi Router (192.168.1.1) and I set to my WR1043ND (192.168.1.200). I enabled the WDS Bridging, and assigned the right SSID. 

If I'm connected to my main Wifi router, I can reach without any problem my repeater WR1043ND (192.168.1.200). My problem is I have some Ethernet port connected to various devices, and if try to reach them connected to my main Wifi router, it failed. But If I connect by Wifi the repeater using his own SSID, I can read all those devices, but not the one from the main router.

Comment: How is the WR1043ND connected to the main router? To which one are connected the Ethernet devices? Maybe adding to the post a schema of your local network will make it clearer.

Comment: Here is a quick schema [img](https://i.imgur.com/pXHo2cg.png)
My problem is 192.168.1.10 can reach the TPlink Admin (192.168.1.200) while it can't access to 192.168.1.110. 

And 192.168.1.110 can't reach either Internet or 192.168.1.10

Comment: Are both routers WR1043ND? Because the instructions you followed will only work if both routers are TP-Link, dual-band green UI routers. Otherwise, at a minimum, note 3 doesn't apply.

Comment: Nope they are not both WR1043ND, only the repeater is WR1043ND

Comment: What is the main router? Does it have a setting for AP Isolation? Try to disable (temporarily) firewalls on both routers (actually the WR1043ND doesn't need it).

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same issue. Main router is Velop, bridging to Tp-Link Archer c9, and a raspberry pi 2 connected via lan to the Tp-Link doesn't get internet

Answer (score 0):

If you only have devices on one of them. Just put a route to deliver the packets from that network on the router (Default Gateway) that has the devices directly connected.
In other cases you can had specific routing lines to each device so everyone on the network knows in wich router is going to connect to that device.